# Which element is selected at designtime

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm programming Windows phone app and trerefor using XAML but I find i VERY difficult to see in the XAML code which element is selected.

[image]

Have a look at this picture:
At designtime I've selected a TextBlock and so it is in the XAML code. But it's not very clear.

My question is: Can I some how change the selection color in the XAML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting responsible for the color is `Inactive Selected Text`. In Visual Studio go to `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors` and change the color to your desired value.

Changing the value will also affect the highlighting of your normal code files. There is no distinction between XAML and other code files.